# SAS Exporting to Excel Template - Retain Formatting

Tags: excel

I'm using Excel templates to output from SAS into a pre-existing .xls template.

[Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5SHF.png)

When I output through SAS, using the below code, it ruins the formatting and looks awful. I'd like to retain formatting but I don't even know what's causing this issue to fix it. WORK.REGS is the data I'm outputting to the 'registrations' data range in my Excel template.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNvpw.png)

```
    X "%str(copy /Y      %"&file.\Template\TEMPLATE.xls %" 
              %"&file.\Output.xls %" )";

libname test pcfiles path="&file.\Output.xls";

proc datasets lib = test nolist;
delete  registrations ;
quit;


data    test.registrations ;
set     regs;
run ;

libname test clear ;
```

Comment: Did you find the answer to this question? I am also facing the same challenge; exporting data from SAS dataset to pre-designed excel workbook.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the person in the office who I thought was out today (and who I figured could help).

This wasn't anything to do with SAS in itself. The cells where the data is output to are formatted as general, but SAS sees them as being text or numbers. Formatting the Excel cells to be text meant the number cells were now losing formatting. Formatting the text cells to be text and the number cells to be numbers in the template fixed this issue.

Hope this is useful to anybody else who might have similar issues in the future.